# crontab set two lib path

Tags: bash, cron

I am running programs in crontab environment. I got error as

> "./ungrib.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libnuma.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

The `libnuma.so` is under one lib path, but my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already set to be for another lib path.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just for the execution of your command:

```
* * * * * LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib /path/to/command args
```